# Make Search bar dynamically appear at top of body

Tags: module, menu, custom-module, search

One of our clients would like to have a search icon in their Main menu, which when clicked causes a search bar to appear at the top of the website's body. An example of this behaviour is at https://www.bioped.com/ . We have looked for Joomla extensions that do this for us, but haven't managed to find anything.

How should something like this be accomplished in the Joomla framework? I feel like this will involve writing a custom search module somehow. I have written modules and plugins, but I haven't written any yet that needs to access Joomla's built-in search functionality. Making the search bar appear seems like it should be relatively simple javascript (?), but it's not clear to me how to put the clickable search icon in the main menu.

Any help would be appreciated since I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: From what I can see the Java script appears to toggle the search container between a height of 0px and 50px with inline style of the <form>. In Joomla I would say you you could set up a similar Search Module with a height of 0px in the top position of your template and create a similar menu item to toggle the Height.